# I have a line from Point A to B and I want to extend the line to Point C upto outer radius in the same angle in canvas CustomPainter Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, math, canvas

I have the coordinates of Point A(x1,y1) and Point B(x2,y2) and I want to extend the line to Point C(x3, y3) upto outer radius in the same angle in canvas CustomPainter Flutter. How to find the value of x3 and y3?. If I get the Point C I can use drawLine function to draw straight from Point A to C

Comment: Your question is unclear. Perhaps you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556468/how-to-create-a-line-whose-head-is-some-distance-from-its-end-java-awt/55559073#55559073)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic trigonometry will get what you need:

```js
let A = { x: 10, y: 10 };
let B = { x: 80, y: 20 };
let radius = 100


let angle = Math.atan2(B.y - A.y, B.x - A.x)
let C = {
  x: B.x + Math.cos(angle) * radius,
  y: B.y + Math.sin(angle) * radius
};


const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.rect(A.x, A.y, 2, 2);
ctx.rect(B.x, B.y, 2, 2);
ctx.rect(C.x, C.y, 2, 2);

ctx.moveTo(A.x, A.y);
ctx.lineTo(C.x, C.y);

ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

What we know Points **A**, **B** and **radius**...
with Points **A** and **B** we can calculate the angle of the line
that is:
`Math.atan2(B.y - A.y, B.x - A.x)`

Then with that angle and the radius we can calculate point **C**:

```
let C = {
  x: B.x + Math.cos(angle) * radius,
  y: B.y + Math.sin(angle) * radius
};
```

Only assumption is the start of the radius, on this case I'm assuming is from point B

All that remains is to draw something with that